# Count number of grep occurrences and store it a variable

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I want to do something like this - grep for a string in a particular file, store it in a variable and be able to print just the number of occurrences.

```
#!/bin/bash
count=$(grep *something* *somefile*| wc -l)
echo $count
```

This always gives a 0 value, when I know it should be more.

This is what I intend to do, but its taking like forever to finish the script.

```
if egrep -iq "Android 6.0.1" $filename; then
        count=$(egrep -ic "Android 6.0.1" $filename)
        echo 'Operating System Version leaked number of times: '$count
```

I have 7 other such if statements and I am running this for around 20 files.

Any more efficient way to make it faster?

Comment: Maybe try quoting the match part of grep. `grep "something" file`

Comment: Also note that `grep -c` can count the lines without the need to call `wc`.

Comment: Try to give a [mcve]  so we can have more insight. The code seems to be ok.

Comment: You are calling grep once to see if a regexp exists in your file and then calling grep again to count how many times that same regexp exists in your file. I'm sure if you really thought about that you could come up with a way to improve the efficiency of that code yourself.

Answer (score 2):

`grep` has its own counting flag

> -c, --count
>
> Suppress normal output; instead **print a count of matching lines** for
>   each input file. With the -v, --invert-match option (see below), count
>   non-matching lines. (-c is specified by POSIX .)

```
count=$( grep -c 'match' file)
```

Note that the match part is quoted as well so if you use special characters they are not interpreted by the shell.

Also as stated in the excerpt from that man page multiple matches on a single line will be counted as a single match as it only counts matching lines:

```
$ echo "hello hello hello hello
hello
> bye" | grep -c "hello"
2
```

Comment: @fedorqui forgot to clarify that yes. It does say it in the excerpt but maybe it's not clear. Thanks

Comment: I added an example to clarify this. Feel free to rollback if you don't think it should be there.

Comment: @fedorqui nope it's fine :)

Comment: Thank @123. I was using grep -q and was not getting any value. Could you explain why?

Comment: @SurajBhatia If you read the man page then you would see that `-q` is quiet and does not give any output

Answer (score 1):

A much more efficient approach would be to run Awk once.

```
awk -v patterns="foo,bar,baz" 'BEGIN { n=split(patterns, pats, ",") }
    { for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) if ($0 ~ pats[i]) ++hits[i] }
    END { for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) printf("%8d%s\n", hits[i], pats[i]) }' list of files
```

For bonus points, format the output in machine-readable format (depending on where it ends up, JSON might be a good choice); and/or add the human-readable explanation for the significance of each hit to the END block.

If that's not what you want, running `grep -Eic` and ditching any zero value would already improve your run time over grepping the file twice for each match in the worst case.  (The pessimal situation would be when the last line and no other line matches your pattern.)